# Firebase Hosting - Infinite Redirects

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to use redirects option to redirect visitors to canonical page urls. For example:

- https://example.com/page1/index.html should become https://example.com/page1/,
  and
- https://example.com/page2// should become https://example.com/page2/

After reading the documentation I created these redirection rules:

```
"redirects": [
  {
    "source": "/:url/index.html",
    "destination": "/:url/",
    "type": 301
  },
  {
    "source": "/:url//",
    "destination": "/:url/",
    "type": 301
  }
],
```

This successfully redirects `/page/index.html` to `/page/`, but after that it falls into infinite redirect loop. It seems that `"source": "/:url//"` matches both `/page//` and `/page/`.

What is the correct way to specify regex rule to match only double slashes?

Comment: Hello, no updates so far ?